# How to mock ExceptionContext for testing using .NET Core 3 Web API and Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, moq, xunit

In order to properly test a custom ExceptionFilterAttribute in .NET Core 3 we need to mock an ExceptionContext in an Xunit test using Moq. How can I do this?

Exception Filter:

```
public class CustomExceptionFilter : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
  public override OnException(ExceptionContext context)
  {
    /* Code here that handles exceptions */
  }
}
```

I've looked everywhere and can't figure out a good way to mock these things in a way that ensures nothing throws an exception due to other missing dependencies. How can I mock `ExceptionContext` easily?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem lies in the fact that if you are trying to mock `ExceptionContext` in order to return different exception types, you actually want to mock an exception and then use that mock exception when instantiating the `ExceptionContext`.

First, to instantiate the `ExceptionContext` for filters in a test you need to be able to instantiate the `ActionContext`. The `ActionContext` is not relevant to our test but is required by the dependency tree so we must instantiate it with as little customization as possible:

```
var actionContext = new ActionContext()
{
  HttpContext = new DefaultHttpContext(),
  RouteData = new RouteData(),
  ActionDescriptor = new ActionDescriptor()
};
```

After you are able to instantiate the `ActionContext` you can instantiate the ExceptionContext. Here we are also mocking the exception that is being used to build the `ExceptionContext`. This is the most important step as this is the value which changes the behavior we are testing.

```
// The stacktrace message and source member variables are virtual and so we can stub them here.
var mockException = new Mock<Exception>();

mockException.Setup(e => e.StackTrace)
  .Returns("Test stacktrace");
mockException.Setup(e => e.Message)
  .Returns("Test message");
mockException.Setup(e => e.Source)
  .Returns("Test source");

var exceptionContext = new ExceptionContext(actionContext, new List<FilterMetadata>())
{
  Exception = mockException.Object
};
```

Doing it this way allows you to adequately test the behavior of an exception filter when given different exception types.

Full code:

```
[Fact]
public void TestExceptionFilter()
{
  var actionContext = new ActionContext()
  {
    HttpContext = new DefaultHttpContext(),
    RouteData = new RouteData(),
    ActionDescriptor = new ActionDescriptor()
  };

  // The stacktrace message and source member variables are virtual and so we can stub them here.
  var mockException = new Mock<Exception>();

  mockException.Setup(e => e.StackTrace)
    .Returns("Test stacktrace");
  mockException.Setup(e => e.Message)
    .Returns("Test message");
  mockException.Setup(e => e.Source)
    .Returns("Test source");

  // the List<FilterMetadata> here doesn't have much relevance in the test but is required 
  // for instantiation. So we instantiate a new instance of it with no members to ensure
  // it does not effect the test.
  var exceptionContext = new ExceptionContext(actionContext, new List<FilterMetadata>())
  {
    Exception = mockException.Object
  };

  var filter = new CustomExceptionFilter();

  filter.OnException(exceptionContext);

  // Assumption here that your exception filter modifies status codes.
  // Just used as an example of how you can assert in this test.
  context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode.Should().Be(500, 
    "Because the response code should match the exception thrown.");
}
```